# Detect click on UIScrollView's child

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, segue

I have `UITableView` with cells. These cells have `segues` (on click I go to other ViewControllers).

If I add a `UITableView` inside a `UIScrollView`, the click on the cell does not work, because I click on my `UIScrollView`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: google "cancel touches property of uiscrollview"

Comment: it's not about question, but why do you put your tableview inside scrollview?

Comment: because my menu (tableview) contains very many items and I need scroll them